Can not make use of ShadcnUI Navigation Menu
I'm trying to make use of Chadcn navigation in my Next.js 14 header compoenent. So I use just the one suggested in the docs:
import {auth} from '@/auth'
 
import {
  NavigationMenu,
  NavigationMenuContent,
  NavigationMenuIndicator,
  NavigationMenuItem,
  NavigationMenuLink,
  NavigationMenuList,
  NavigationMenuTrigger,
  NavigationMenuViewport,
} from "@/components/ui/navigation-menu"

const Header = async () => {
    const session = await auth()

    let authContent : React.ReactNode;

    if (session?.user) {
        authContent = <div className="avatar placeholder">
        <div className="bg-neutral text-neutral-content rounded-full w-25">
            
        </div>
      </div> 
    } else {
        authContent =   
             
         <ul className="p-2">
            <li><a>Login</a></li>
            <li><a>Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        
    }
    return ( 

      <NavigationMenu>
      <NavigationMenuList>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger>Item One</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
            <NavigationMenuLink>Link</NavigationMenuLink>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
      </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>

 
     );
}
 
export default Header;

However I get this error:
 TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs:11:114)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-direction/dist/index.mjs (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/vendor-chunks/@radix-ui.js:60:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs:31:83)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu/dist/index.mjs (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/vendor-chunks/@radix-ui.js:90:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx:17:89)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/app/page.js:443:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/components/header.tsx:8:88)
    at (rsc)/./src/components/header.tsx (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/app/page.js:403:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx:12:76)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/layout.tsx (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/app/page.js:359:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (/home/me/dev/discuss/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at async e9 (/home/me/dev/discuss/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:396515)
    at async tb (/home/me/dev/discuss/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400212)
    at async tS (/home/me/dev/discuss/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:400773)
    at async tR (/home/me/dev/discuss/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2130)
    at async /home/me/dev/discuss/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2722 {
  digest: '717147068',
  page: '/'
}
 ○ Compiling /_error ...

The header itself works fine without this NavigationMenu component.  So I'm wondering what is wrong there and how to fix it?
My package.json is like this:
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "^0.18.1",
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^2.1.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.14.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.379.0",
    "next": "^14.2.3",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
    "prisma": "^5.14.0",
    "radix-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


Extract your code below into a NavComponent as client component. I'm not able to explain yet why NavigationMenu needs to be in a client component.
<NavigationMenu>
  <NavigationMenuList>
    <NavigationMenuItem>
      <NavigationMenuTrigger>Item One</NavigationMenuTrigger>
      <NavigationMenuContent>
        <NavigationMenuLink>Link</NavigationMenuLink>
      </NavigationMenuContent>
    </NavigationMenuItem>
  </NavigationMenuList>
</NavigationMenu>

